What hardware do I need to create my own Ring doorbell clone?
I like the idea of the Ring doorbell. I do not like the idea of my audio & video passing through google's servers.
I can code app app to send/receive from the "doorbell", via my server, to a 'phone app which I can also code (having said that, suggestions for code libraries are welcome).
I generally use ESP32, though I have also used STM, R. Pi, etc
I need, for the doorbell, something with a display, in case I want the ringer to see me, a camera, so I can see them, and a microphone & a speaker for 2-way audio. I am not great at soldering, being a softie, and would prefer a single unit, or multiple plug & play parts, e.g Seeed's grove connector, etc
And, I guess that I would need an IP67 housing for it too.
What's the simplest hardware set up of that?

[Update] I wonder if I could use Wireshark to find the protocol that Ring uses, then buy a Ring and intercept its traffic

NB: ring is an Amazon product, not Google. Are you able to power the doorbell via an external source (and if so, what kind?), or should it run solely on battery, using wireless? Is the visitor-facing display an absolute requirement? What size do you need? Have you looked into M5Stack’s products?

I know people that can do this project who, regardless, bought COTS camera door bells. And that's w/o 2 way video. For 2 way video ... think about the smallest thing you can pull off a zoom call on. Yes, probably an Android phone/tablet. Since you are more software then hardware, I think that's what you need to set your sights on. At me if you'll accept an answer like that and I'll post more details. Otherwise there are a lot of eager stackexchange "people" as of late that like to down vote any answer that doesn't answer the question directly...and you said "hardware" in your opening question.

@jcaron I imagine that batteries won't last long, so I would have to figure out who to power it from the mains. I suppose that I can live without the ringer seeing me, just thought it would be "nice to have". I do like M5Stack, with that sweet, sweet Grove plug & play. https://shop.m5stack.com/products/unit-cams3-wi-fi-camera-5mp looks good, but only has a mic, so I wold have to Grove a speaker, and that might make a housing tricky. Also, see update to question

@st2000 Sure, I'd like to see your answer. I think that I could live without 2 way video. Also, see update to question

You are dropping 2way video? That was a major reason I suggested an Android platform. If 1way video is the new direction, then why not just use a ESP32-WIFI-Camera for video and cobble something together for 2way-full-duplex-audio. I suspect the reason batteries were brought up is because some COTS smart-door-bells demand more current when operating than the old door bell transformer can deliver.  But the old transformers can charge batteries which can deliver the high operating current demand over a short period of time.

What would you recommend, to add audio?  Also, check out https://reolink.com/

"...recommend, to add audio"? Anything. You haven't set any requirements. Could be old school analog over wires. Could be VOIP over WIFI. "Also check out ..."? Almost every security camera OEM has a video+2-way-audio option. If that's and option, why not the "Ring"? I recall because you do not want to use their "cloud". Are you sure you have to? Also, as it looks like you are not building stuff & "cloud" adversed, have you checked if any of the "Ring" copy-cats offer up a non-cloud smart door bell?

Thanks for that. I hinestly don't care about how the audio is done, as long as its there. I am intrguied by the "Ring" copy-cats offer up a non-cloud smart door bell. But, would they allow me to view/talk remotely? E.g from the office

I don't normally suggest a product and I'll clarify that I haven't actually done this (yet) but the following 2 reolink doorbells support ONVIF.
https://store.reolink.com/gb/video-doorbells/
Comes in either WiFi (looks to be powered by a bell transformer) or Enternet with PoE for power.
This combined with go2rtc https://github.com/AlexxIT/go2rtc should be able to do what you want.
go2rtc can connect to the camera and provide a webrtc feed. Assuming you have a fixed IP (or DDNS) you can use this to view the camera with low latency from any browser. You'll have to double check the 2 way voice works, but it does with Tapo ONVIF camera, so it should be possible.
The last thing to check would be actual bell push notification and person detection, will need to check if that can do a local http callback.
But this would be COTS hardware that is built for the job and a raspberry pi can stand in for the cloud side of things without the cloud.
This isn't meant to be an advert or a recommendation just a suggestion at existing specific hardware that while it might come with a cloud service, it could be replaced by all self hosted software.
p.s. they do appear to be fully supported by Home Assistant https://www.home-assistant.io/integrations/reolink/
